# Dropzone + Jquery-ui sortable not calling the update event when certain condition is met

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, vuejs2, dropzone.js

I'm porting an old app from pure jquery to Vue + some jquery, and Dropzone.js and jquery-ui Sortable function to rearrange a gallery is something is staying the same for the most part, this is what I have which is similar as the previous code:

```
import {Dropzone} from 'dropzone';
require('jquery-ui/ui/widgets/draggable');
require('jquery-ui/ui/widgets/droppable');
require('jquery-ui/ui/widgets/sortable');
require('jquery-ui/ui/disable-selection');

methods: {
   InitializeSortable(destroy = false) {
       const selfComponent = this;

       if (destroy) {
           $('#gallery-container').sortable('refresh');
       }

       $('#gallery-container').sortable({
           change: function (event, ui) {
               console.log('called change')
               ui.placeholder.css(
                   {
                       'visibility': 'visible',
                       'border': '1px solid#337ab7',
                       'border-radius': '10px'
                   }
               );
           },
           update: function (event, ui) {
               console.log('called update')
               selfComponent.RearrangeGalleryFiles();
           },
           zIndex: 1003,
           tolerance: 'pointer',
           items: '.dz-preview',
           cancel: '.dz-add-image, .ui-sortable-handle'
       }).disableSelection();
   },
}
```

There's only 2 things changing:

- The fact I'm using Vue 2.7.14 and
- Using imports and requires to get the code from Dropzone and Jquery-ui
- Also maybe Dropzone's version

Now, the issue is explained this way:
I have image 1, then image 2 to the right. I drag image 2 and drop it to image 1, so both images swap positions, if I drag image 1 towards image 2 so they would swap again and get back to their original positions the update event won't fire at all.

The update event fires if I drag image 2 to image 1 and then attempt another drag but this time dragging image 2 again towards image 1 (meaning that the drag origin element has to be always the same one).

The point is that seems like both elements stop being recognized by sortable and even the code `$('#gallery-container').children('.dz-preview')` (which I use to rearrange in another function) makes the page crash and asks for a refresh, something weird is happening here, although both elements are still there in the DOM.

I have a small GIF to demonstrate what I'm talking about:

[image]

You can see how change gets called in but update stops being called all together.

Is there a cause and a solution for this issue?

Thanks in advance.